# Issues installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Cluster. While installing the first node, I keep on getting the following error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup
>   
> The following error has occurred:
>   
> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
>   
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

Has anyone seen this issue before? I have uninstalled it multiple times and tried re-installing it but same results.

Comment: Are you installing from RTM media? Have you attempted to [slipstream](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955392) with [Service Pack 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27594) before starting the install? Also are you running as a domain admin and have you [disabled things like UAC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2526083)?

Comment: I am currently installing it using SQL2008 full version which slipsteam SP1

Comment: Yes I am running as local administrator and running install "As Administrator"

Comment: Maybe I should disable UAC and then try it

Comment: Why would you want to be on an unsupported service pack? I strongly recommend you consider SP3.

Comment: My plan was to install SQL and then install SP3 and SP3 CU2 since all other servers in the environment are at SP3 CU2

Comment: You can slipstream both SP3 and CU2, saving you multiple steps. And this patches setup, so if the problem you're having running setup has been fixed in more recent patches, win-win!

Comment: hmmm... I can give that a try. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If that doesn't help, you should post your setup logs to http://connect.microsoft.com/sql/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Aaron B. for the help. The issue seems to be with the server itself. I had SA reimage the server and now SQL installed without any issues.

Comment: If this worked (install a new image), please mark this as the answer. This way the question doesn't appear unsolved.